# Increase margin of figure to include long labels

Tags: r, plot

Essentially, I want to make sure that all my labels on the x-axis are non-overlapping and that the figure margins are long enough to see vertical labels.

```
par(mar=c(180, 70, 2, 2.1)) 
oldfont <- par(font=3) 
table(new$Tag)
barplot(table(new$Tag),x,las=2,cex.lab=100)
```

Please find bar plot image here!

[image]

Comment: Please include a complete example, to help us have something to work on. You can embed images, also makes it easier for us.

Comment: Hi AkselA -> thanks for your feedback. I included a picture of my bar plot. Are you not able to view it? It could be possible that you have to click on a link since it seems I don't have enough reputation to post a image straight to the text field. Sorry about that.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you needed a certain amount of rep to post an image, but I can see it now yes.

Comment: I notice that a good number of the categories have a count of one. Could it be a possibility to remove those from the bar plot and inform the reader separately about these?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something more than just changing the margins, text size etc.?
Readability can be improve a bit by censoring out the single-counts and truncating the names.

```
set.seed(1)

words <- sapply(
  sample(3:25, 50, replace=TRUE), 
  function(x) {
      paste(sample(c(letters), x, replace=TRUE), collapse="")
      }
)

strtrunc <- function(x, l, r="…") {
    trunc <- nchar(x) > l
    x[trunc] <- paste0(strtrim(x[trunc], l), r)
    x
}


samp <- sample(1:50, 500, replace=TRUE)
samp.t <- round(1.2^table(samp))
samp.t[sample(1:50, 20)] <- 1
names(samp.t) <- words

dev.new(width=10, height=5)
par(mar=c(10, 4, 3, 0.5), mgp=c(0, 0.8, -0.5), cex=0.9)
b <- barplot(samp.t, xaxt="n", space=0.5, col=1)
axis(1, at=b, labels=names(samp.t), las=2, tick=FALSE, cex.axis=0.8)
mtext("All counts", line=1, cex=1.5)

#barplot with logarithmic y-axis, truncated names and no single-counts
samp.ts <- samp.t[samp.t != 1]
names(samp.ts) <- strtrunc(names(samp.ts), 15)

dev.new(width=10, height=5)
par(mar=c(10, 4, 3, 0.5), mgp=c(0, 0.8, -0.5), cex=0.9)
b <- barplot(samp.ts, xaxt="n", space=0.5, col=1, log="y")
axis(1, at=b, labels=names(samp.ts), las=2, tick=FALSE, cex.axis=1.2)
mtext("Counts > 1", line=1, cex=1.5)
```

[image]
[image]

Bar plots with more than 20 or so named categories generally doesn't really work so well, you'd might be better off finding a different way to visualize your data. Histogram or density plot might be an option, if it makes sense for your data. Otherwise breaking the bar plot up into smaller sections, maybe by sensible groups, might be another.

Comment: +1 for suggesting a different type of visualization. Graphs should strive to distill clear visual stories from complex data sets, not simply serve as raw data dumps.